# async giving callback already called error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack, async.js

I am trying to achieve the following scenario. But while executing I am getting an error *Uncaught Error: Callback was already called.*

Can anyone find what I am doing wrong ?

```
async.forEachOf(code,function(item, index, done){
    var currentItemId = item.id;    
    var subitemCount = item.subitem;
    for(var k=0; k< subitemCount ; k++){
         $.ajax({
            url: 'api/item' + k,
            success: function(result) {              
             code["allSub"].push(result);
             done();
            },
            error: function(err) {                
                done(err);             
            }
        })
    }
},function(){
    console.log(code);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in the `for(var k=0; k< subitemCount ; k++){` declaration.

Notice that for each `item.subitem` you are making one ajax call. And for after each of those calls return, you are calling the `done()` callback. Therefore the code is actually calling the callback (i.e. `done()`) multiple times. Once for each ajax call and thus once for each `item.subitem`.

That's why you're having the *Uncaught Error: Callback was already called.*

In order to avoid this, you'd need to make another `async.forEachOf` instead of the

Try using this:

```
async.forEachOf(code,function(item, index, doneItem){
    var currentItemId = item.id;    
    var subitemCount = item.subitem;
    async.forEachOf(subitemCount, function (subItem, subItemIndex, subItemDone){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/item' + subItemIndex,
            success: function(result) {              
                code["allSub"].push(result);
                subItemDone();
            },
            error: function(err) {                
                subItemDone(err);             
            }
        })
    }, function(err) {
        //Called once all the current item's subItems ajax calls were finished 
        doneItem(err);
    }


},function(){
    //Called once all items in "code" finished their own subItem ajax calls
    console.log(code);
});
```

If `item.subitem` is a numeric value instead of an array, you can try using the [`async.times`](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md#timesn-iterator-callback)

```
async.forEachOf(code,function(item, index, doneItem){
    var currentItemId = item.id;    
    var subitemCount = item.subitem;
    async.times(subitemCount, function (subItemIndex, subItemDone){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/item' + subItemIndex,
            success: function(result) {     
                code["allSub"].push(results);         
                subItemDone();
            },
            error: function(err) {                
                subItemDone(err);             
            }
        })
    }, function(err, results) {
        //Called once all subItem ajax calls were finished
        doneItem(err);
    }


},function(){
    //Called once all items in "code" finished their own subItem ajax calls
    console.log(code);
});
```